# Does SOAP have to be stateful?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

REST is clearly Stateless, meaning the request to the server contains all the information that the server requires to understand it, the server does not maintain a session.

Now my question is, does SOAP has to be stateful, I have worked with SOAP where the exact definition of REST would seem to be true for SOAP as well?

Comment: -1: question proceeds from a false premise, and also from a false understanding of REST

Comment: Stateful webservices are bothersome, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588378/stateful-vs-stateless-webservices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now my question is Does SOAP HAVE to be state-full..

No. SOAP *can* be stateful, but it definitely doesn't have to be. Actually, you have to put some effort in order to achieve stateful behaviour. I suggest reading [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40558).